# Xamarin iOS - Is it possible to have a "Unified- Single View" project target iOS 6.x?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'd like to be able to use a single view project with iOS 6. The only options I have when creating the project are 8.0 to 8.4

Am I missing something or am I stuck with this?

If I'm stuck what is the simplest template I can use that will work with iOS 6 and not use the classic API?

I really just need a single view that has some text output to the screen to confirm connection to a 3rd party API.
Thanks!

Comment: I doubt it.  Unified was introduced for 64 bit support, which became a requirement with iOS 8.

Comment: Yeah, I it doesn't seem that way, but you think you'd be able to set the minimum API level to iOS 6 and build for multiple architectures.

Comment: So I can use an "Empty project" and target iOS 6. I wonder what the difference is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Xamarin.iOS unified project from whatever template you feel like (i.e. Single View) and then open *Info.plist* and set the Deployment Target to 6.0.

Comment: Thanks! I did notice that have you done this and confirmed that it works?